# How can I search for the most viewed questions?

Tags: support, questions, views

Is there a way to know about the most viewed questions of a Stack Exchange site?

The *Frequent* heading under *Questions* gives something else (though close enough).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This data.SE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/263999/most-views) shows top 200 questions with most views. Also, on Stack Overflow itself you can search for questions with views>X, e.g. [`views:10000`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A10000).

And "frequent" section gives the questions with most links to other questions on SO.